# Invoke a method in dotnet assembly on MS access DB

Tags: database, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have the below scenario.

1. We have MS access DB where system inserts the records randomly and we don't have control on  insertion
2. I need to call a method which sends email when any record is inserted.

I have the functionality in place to send email, but only thing is need to catch the event exactly when record being inserted on Access

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access doesn't support triggers thus you will have to write a utility which "queries" the table for new records every X minutes and runs as a service on a machine with connectivity to the database and email servers.

or don't use access and find a database which does support triggers and call outs to external programs.